# Will a jet flown on a parabolic arc reach its highest altitude on a warm day or a cold one?

Tags: aircraft-performance, weather, temperature

In level flight, on cold days jet-powered planes can fly higher because the air is denser. However, at the same time the true airspeed is lower because of the denser air.

At warmer temperatures a plane accelerates to a higher airspeed, and as a result the higher speed could allow for enough initial speed to reach higher peak altitudes when flown in a steep parabolic arc.

Can a (military jet) plane fly higher in a parabolic flight when the air is warmer?

Comment: Interesting question! I reworded it to make it clearer, let me know if this still captures your intent. BTW, is it true that planes accelerate more quickly when the air is thinner? I would have thought the opposite, since there is less oxygen. And did you mean higher delta-v, or higher kinetic energy?

Comment: @KennSebesta You're right as technically the plane's delta-v is always the same, I rather mean kinetic energy, I clarified that. Rather than accelerating more quickly the plane reaches a higher true airspeed than at colder temperatures (but this goes hand in hand), and I think it really works, higher apogees can be achieved. The reason the plane goes faster is the warm air which is less dense so there is less air resistance I guess.

Comment: This is a very interesting questìon, and not a trivial one to answer. Yes, in hotter air TAS is higher, but how about engine efficiency? And how about lift, which is also imperative when considering flying parabolic, (but not ballistic) trajectories.

Comment: @Jpe61 Um, wait, what's the difference between parabolic and ballistic trajectories? My question is concerning those that fly as high as possible, with a high pitch, to altitudes 110~130,000 ft where air is near vacuum.

Comment: Strictly speakin ballistic trajectory is "the path of an unpowered object, as a missile".

Comment: @Jpe61 Since the plane is entering near-vacuum and eventually floats on inertia only, I'd say it's a parabolic-turned-ballistic trajectory.

Comment: Yes, but what I'm after is, that since the question is about a military jet, the procedure would be a zoom climb, so all kinds of aerodynamics are involved. Or are you asking specifically about the portion when the jet is already in the ballistic phase of flight?

Comment: @Jpe61 Um, I dunno. The entire flight pattern I'd say. Or rather the initial horizontal flight before starting the zoom climb. E.g. in cold air the plane cannot gather enough speed (or only after a long time) to eventually reach an apogee as high as in warmer air I guess, because when it's cold the denser atmosphere means more air resistance so that in warm air you can fly faster, that's how I understand it if I'm correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maximum airspeed of any aircraft is determined by thrust and drag$^1$.

At first glance it would seem lower density of warm air would favor faster true airspeed (more kinetic energy to climb), but (for airbreathing engines) one can consider the effects of warmer, less dense air on thrust production as well.

Jet engines rely on delta temperature by combustion of fuel to produce propulsive thrust through the expansion of gasses, just like their piston cousins. Therefor, colder air gives them a double advantage of more oxygen to burn and greater delta T.

This is why airliners like to fly in the *Tropopause*, a region in our atmosphere that is always very cold.

Very luckily, for our parabolic endeavors, the atmosphere warms (and thins) above the tropopause, favoring maximum altitude during the ballistic phase of flight.

Analysis of the flight profiles of the NF-104 and the F-15A "Streak Eagle" show a very similar approach, using maximum thrust to go supersonic in the tropopause, around 6-8 miles high, before angling upwards.

But we must remember to think vertically and have temperature data from all levels of the planned flight.

One other thing about a "cold day" on the ground is that *pressure actually drops faster with altitude*, enough to cause significant altimeter errors in extreme cases.

So, with the Streak Eagle, they did it on a very cold day.

$^1$ and  structural strength to handle that speed

Comment: Pressure drops faster with altitude on colder days?

Comment: Yes, and if it got *much* colder air would be a puddle on the ground.  It's "pressure drops faster with *altitude*".

Comment: In other words, e.g. FL300 above the poles is at a completely different absolute altitude than above the Sahara desert?

Comment: I have heard the stratosphere can be as low as 25,000 feet at the poles.

Comment: Yes that's true (I even mean to have heard 20,000 ft) and at the equator the tropopause can be as high as 70,000 ft, but these values are about where the temperature stops decreasing, and where it starts rising again with altitude. This doesn't have to do with pressure directly, but with temperature and how high cumulonimbus clouds can go.

Comment: @Giovanni pressure is a function of both density and temperature.  Lift at a given airspeed is a function of density.  Jet thrust is a function of density and delta T.  They are all related in the formula PV=nRT.  So you have a taller stack of warmer air to have the same *ground* pressure.

Comment: Why is a greater delta T an advantage? Wouldn't more uniform temps throughout the atmosphere be more advantageous to a plane? The temp of the lower stratosphere isn't a constant minus 56.5°C, it changes with sea level temperature too.

Comment: Greater delta T is an advantage for the the jet engine.  You are right about less dense air (warm) being easier to fly through.  Once in the ballistic phase it would be an advantage.  Under power, greater engine efficiency makes it better to be in colder air.

Comment: Then it's not a _double_ advantage as you write, because the greater delta T provides for more oxygen and thus for more engine efficiency, so it goes all hand in hand.

Comment: The second advantage is greater expansion of gasses.  That's what I mean by delta T.  A third advantage is that aircraft can fly at a lower AOA in denser air for the same lift.  So it is really very complicated.

Comment: The tropopause (in the way you mean it, lower stratosphere in fact) actually extends from 7 to 12 miles (11 to 19 km) before temperature starts rising with altitude again. At 45th latitude of course; on the poles it goes lower and on the equator it goes higher. Airliners fly on the lower edge of the tropopause or even below it, the Concorde flew on its upper edge. On a flight from Europe to America I've flown at an altitude of 30,000 ft which is below the tropopause at 45th latitude, but we flew above Greenland so the temperature remained constant, we were in the tropopause/lower stratosphere.

Comment: Amazing I learn a little bit answering too. Appreciate that.  I would recommend modeling based on *density altitude*.  Since atmosphere is not a closed container, *pressure* differences result in wind flow.  For a given pressure, aviation generally deals with variations in Temperature and Density (rho, literally molecules per volume).  The aircraft must be strong, light, and powerful, striving to hold *lowest drag AoA* all the way up (while still maintaining adequate lift).  A supersonic jet will also have issues slowing through the drag peak at transsonic.

Comment: But since density is dependent on temperature and pressure altitude is universal regardless of temperature, it is good imho.